# Why doesn't HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests cancel pending requests (in a WebApp)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http

I'm trying to make an AspNetCore web app be able to cancel an http request on the server.  In my demo app based on the familiar WeatherForecast demo, on the client:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:5031/weatherforecast";
        _requestTask = _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>(uri);

        IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>? forecasts = await _requestTask;
        _requestTask = null;

        ViewData["WeatherForecastData"] = forecasts;

        return Page();
    }
```

on the server:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool cancel = false;
        cancellationToken.Register(() => {
            cancel = true;
        });

        int count = 5;
        List<WeatherForecast> ret = new List<WeatherForecast>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Iter #{i}");
            if (cancel) // (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
                throw new Exception($"Canceled after {i} forecast items");
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            WeatherForecast wf = new WeatherForecast()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            };
            ret.Add(wf);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The server code loops on creating an item to return, waiting a second on each iteration, and printing a line each time in the Visual Studio output window.  It injects a CancellationToken and registers code to stop the loop.  The client cancel the request:

```
    public void OnPostCancel ()
    {
        //cts.Cancel();
        _httpClient.CancelPendingRequests();
        ViewData["WeatherForecastData"] = new List<WeatherForecast>();
    }
```

and watch the server loop get interrupted with an output window message.

Similar cancel code on a Blazor and a .Net desktop client does interrupt the processing on the server -- you can see that the messages in the output window stop coming, and you get a message about a cancellation.  But for the Web App client, the server doesn't see the cancellation from the injected CancellationToken.

I have a solution on GitHub that demonstrates the issue:
[GitHub permalink](https://github.com/garzooma/CancelDemoBlazor/tree/e3ee94f29ce9a725f0ce48951292f384742f08be)

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? Are there any proxies in between?

Comment: I presume the `_httpClient` is getting recreated on each action here? Not entirely familiar with how Razor Pages work, but I would very much doubt that the server-side object are kept around between requests.

Comment: @StephenCleary: 7.0.11, and no, there are no proxies.  I've tried it on two different desktops.

Comment: @DavidG: Actually, the _httpClient is created on the page:           `public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;  
            this._httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient();  
        }`

Comment: @DavidG: You're right, the _httpClient does get recreated.  The IndexModel ctor is called on each button click, including the Cancel button.  I'm obviously not clear on how these pages work.